# Why does ASP.NET Core 6 MVC Route handler not accept data from axios post request?

Tags: reactjs, axios, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to post an id to the backend and get the expected result, so
here is the code in the frontend side :

```
import axios from "axios"

export async function getList(val) {
    return await axios.post('http://localhost:5107/PlantsInfo', { id:val  }).then(({ data }) => {
        return data;
    });
}
```

and in the backend, I have code something like this:

```
app.MapPost("/PlantsInfo", ([FromServices] DastShafaContext context, int? id) =>
 {
     // database interaction code according to the id
 }
```

When I attempt this and check it by setting a breakpoint, it takes a request but without an id (that is null)...

But when I attempt to pass an id through Postman, everything is okay.

I think it seems the main problem is related to Axios.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how my problem was solved!

```
return await axios.post('http://localhost:5107/GetPlantInfoById?id=' + val).then(({ data }) => {
        return data;
    });
```

But this is not the standard way.
I still welcome the best way